# gluon plugin netbean android version

Tags: netbeans-8, gluon

Where to change the android version to run? Is it in file or in some interface?

My version is 28.

What went wrong:

```
Configured compileSdkVersion is invalid: 27 (C:/android/platforms/android-27).
```

Answer (score 2):

The `jfxmobile` plugin by [default](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/src/tip/src/main/groovy/org/javafxports/jfxmobile/plugin/android/AndroidExtension.groovy?at=default#AndroidExtension.groovy-18) will check for 27, and if it is not found on your system, it will throw an [exception](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/src/tip/src/main/groovy/org/javafxports/jfxmobile/plugin/android/AndroidExtension.groovy?at=default#lines-109) with some explanation:

```
throw new GradleException("Configured compileSdkVersion is invalid: ${compileSdkVersion} (${androidSdk}/platforms/android-${compileSdkVersion}).\n
To fix this, you can do one of the following:\n  
    1. change compileSdkVersion to an installed platform that is available in ${androidSdk}/platforms/\n  
    2. install the android platform version that matches the configured compileSdkVersion:\n
         - from command line run: ${androidSdk}/tools/bin/sdkmanager \"platforms;android-${compileSdkVersion}\"\n     
         - from Android Studio: see https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html")
```

Following option 1 you can change `compileSdkVersion`, and if you have installed version 28, you can do something like:

```
jfxmobile {
    javafxportsVersion = '8.60.11'
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.6'
        plugins 'display', '...
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
    ...
    }
}
```

To find out about the different properties that you can set, see the [documentation](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/5.0.1/#_properties_3).

Comment: Thanks @Jose, I am finding this option too.